# useNavigate blocks rest of the content in createAsyncThunk, redux toolkit

Tags: redux-toolkit

I am trying to access `useNavigate` hooke inside `createAsyncThunk` in redux toolkit as shown below:

```
export const onHandleBookmark = createAsyncThunk('articles/example', async (id: string, { dispatch, getState }) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    console.log('DDD')
    console.log('LLL')
    //rest of the processing
})
```

Unfortunately no logs are getting displayed as it exhausts on first line of execution. Can someone tell me what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a hook like `useNavigate` outside of a component is not allowed - and in this case, it will probably throw an error. Not that this is not really about Redux or createAsyncThunk - it would happen everywhere outside of a component.

If you need accedd to `navigate` outside of Redux components, see [Navigating without the navigation prop](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/)

Answer (score 4):

**Option A (simpler, needs redux-toolkit):**

When using `createAsyncThunk` api, the returned function is *promisified* by default. You can wait for the promise resolution using `unwrap()` method (inpired by [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/error/option_unwrap.html), I guess…). When the promise is resolved, it can be further chained with `then()` calls, so you can navigate from there:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router"
import { logout } from "../store/auth"

const LogoutButton = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  return (  
    <button 
      onClick={() => 
        dispatch(logout()) 
          .unwrap() // <-- async Thunk returns a promise, that can be 'unwrapped')
          .then(() => navigate("/"))
      }
    >
      Log out
    </button>
  )
}
```

**Option B (more [complected](https://youtu.be/LKtk3HCgTa8?t=1896), but works in vanilla react-redux):**

While you cannot call `useNavigate()` outside the React component, you can pass it as an argument to a `dispatch()` call:

**Example component:**

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import { useNavigate } from "react-router"
import { logout } from "../store/auth"

const LogoutButton = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate() // <-- Grab the 'navigate' reference

  return (  
    <button 
      onClick={() => dispatch(logout(navigate))} // <-- Pass 'navigate' as argument
    >
      Log out
    </button>
  )
}
```

**Redux Async Thunk**

Then you can call the function reference passed as argument in the thunk:

```
export const logout = createAsyncThunk(
  "[auth] logout",
  async (navigate) => {
    const response = await axios.get("auth/logout")
    if (response) {
      navigate("/")
      return response
    }
})
```

Comment: Excellent:) You also fixed my problem.